# Accessing Local Network Devices over the Internet

Tags: linux, networking

Here's a diagram of the Network Setup I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

So we have offices with LAN-connected devices that we need to access remotely.

Initial solution is to try using [ZeroTier](https://zerotier.com/)(ZT) installed in a [Ubiquiti EdgeRouter X](https://www.ui.com/edgemax/edgerouter-x/) (UBNT) device.

So I managed to install ZT with the UBNT via its Linux-based *EdgeOS* and SSH:

```
ubnt@ubnt# sudo -i
root@ubnt:~# curl -s https://install.zerotier.com | sudo bash
```

And got to access the Edge OS (Edge Max) interface through the ZeroTier Global IP, so I can access my router anywhere/remotely.

However, how can I "remotely" access the LAN devices connected to the router?
For example, I have one device connected to eth1 with Local IP in the router, `192.168.1.39`

How can I access this using the ZeroTier network?

Here are the interfaces in my EdgeRouter X:

```
ubnt@ubnt:~$ show interfaces
Codes: S - State, L - Link, u - Up, D - Down, A - Admin Down
Interface  IP Address            S/L Description
---------  ----------            --- -----------
eth0     192.168.0.157/24         u/u Internet
eth1     -                 u/u Local
eth2     -                 u/D Local
eth3     -                 u/D Local
eth4     -                 u/D Local
lo      127.0.0.1/8            u/u
       ::1/128
switch0   192.168.1.1/24          u/u Local
ztzlgezugz  10.148.18.15/24          u/D
       fcf0:4d28:e363:18fd:910f::1/40
```

What could be missing in my software and hardware setup to allow the LAN devices to be accessed over the internet?

**UPDATE:**

I also want to emphasize that the Local Instrument/Devices mentioned in the diagram are devices that we cannot install any software into it, neither how the it's network operates. Example are Printers, Scanners, Imaging Devices, NComputing Terminals, etc. We can only access it via LAN.

Comment: Why not use a VPN ?

Comment: Also what do you mean by access? HTTP, SSH, Something else?

Comment: @hardillb over HTTP, SSH, RTSP, etc. any protocol

Comment: I am basing from https://community.ui.com/questions/ZeroTier-SDWAN-on-a-EdgeRouter/fa875bd8-62d7-4cce-9829-ee55ac3d89a5

As a reference.

Comment: if your 3 LANs remain on the same subnet (192.168.1.X), you're going to have some serious issues with routing.

Comment: The steps to solve this is outlined here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1003948/exposing-lan-with-zerotier-when-using-ubiquiti-edge-router-x/1004889#1004889