# Accessing non-HTTPS over VPN is it safe?

Tags: vpn

So I am using [ZeroTier VPN](https://www.zerotier.com/) to access local devices, routers(to which I installed ZT on the router, explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003948/exposing-lan-with-zerotier-when-using-ubiquiti-edge-router-x)), local servers and devices remotely. However, accessing my router for example I only access it without HTTP, e.g. `http://192.168.1.1` which is basically the same way I do when I am physically near the router itself.

On my laptop, there's the ZeroTier Virtual network adapter which is the one handling my access to the IP mentioned so even I am away from the physical location, I can access the router as if I am there, hence, VPN.

My question is, accessing non-HTTPS over VPN is it safe to access non-HTTPS devices? Usually passwords / sessions are part of HTTP payload either through HTTP query parameters or headers.

Comment: Safe from what, or whom?

Comment: From getting the password over the network by analyzing the HTTP transport.

Comment: no is it not safe

Comment: @simon why is that when the transport is through ZeroTier which is a secure network

Comment: Can you explain further? @simon

Comment: because no-http is not safe even in vpn  because it is very easier stone data

Answer (score 2):

Any VPN can only protect from eavesdropping between the two endpoints of the VPN, i.e. your computer and the VPN server. The VPN traffic itself is encrypted, (in theory; with ZeroTier you have to trust them) so it doesn't matter if the payload is plaintext. If you make a plaintext HTTP request then it will not be encrypted in any way between the VPN server and the destination web server.

Comment: I have this setup, the router having ZeroTier is installed physically on a remote location, the access the to web server (i.e. the router web server) is inside the router box only, the router software running as webserver and installed on it's operating system software also, the ZeroTier VPN software, so it does not leave the box. And I am accessing the router web server through the ZeroTier VPN on my computer, so it goes like: `My Laptop --> ZeroTier  Network adapter ---> (ZeroTier Network) ---> Router's ZeroTier interface --> Router web server` does this fit your description?